# Razor syntax prevents escaping HTML in an ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an ASP MVC 3 site and we are trying to put some styling into the action links.

I want the html to be something like `<a href="/somepath/someaction"><span class="someclass">some text</span> some more text</a>` but I can't figure out how to tell Razor to render the `<span>` of it correctly.

What I've tried so far:

```
@Html.ActionLink("<span class="someclass">some text</span> some more text", SomeAction, SomeController);
```

results in a link that looks like: `<span class="someclass">some text</span> some more text`

```
@Html.ActionLink("<text><span class="someclass">some text</span></text> some more text", SomeAction, SomeController);
```

results in a link that looks like: `<text><span class="someclass">some text</span></text> some more text`

```
@Html.ActionLink(<text>"<span class="someclass">some text</span> some more text"</text>, SomeAction, SomeController);
```

results in a compilation error.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `ActionLink` method cannot take HTML.

You need to make a normal `<a>` tag, and use `@Url.Action(...)` for the `href`.