# @Html.ActionLink link text containing HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Razor syntax prevent escaping html in an action link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059805/razor-syntax-prevent-escaping-html-in-an-action-link)

Hi all,

Must be an easy way to do this but have tried and failed thus far...

Have a @Html.ActionLink and within the link text I'd like to render a span. Currently doing so encodes the  element and it's rendered as text on the page.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Here's some text <span class='myClass'>inside the span</span>"), "ActionName", "ControllerName")
```

Any ideas how I get the link text to handle HTML and render it correctly?

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 2):

The `ActionLink` method can only take plain text.

You should write your own `<a>` tag and use `@Url.Action(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `ActionLink` method always HTML-encodes the link text parameter. You would have to write your own version of the helper that does not perform such encoding.