# How to generate link using @Html.ActionLink() in ASP .NET MVC Razor view engine if link text contains html, which should be rendered too?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Razor syntax prevent escaping html in an action link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059805/razor-syntax-prevent-escaping-html-in-an-action-link)

How can I generate link, which contains image, using ASP.NET MVC Razor view engine `@Html.ActionLink()` method. This method takes inner link text as first parameter, so I tried:

```
@{
string linkInnerHtml = string.Format("<img src=\"{0}\" /> Tiles", MyClass.GetImgSrc());
}
@Html.ActionLink(linkInnerHtml, "action" ... )
```

but, as a result, I got link with `<img src="/source.img" /> Tiles` inner text. HTML didn't render.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Write it out longhand, using [`Url.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to render the `href` attribute value.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("action"...)">
  <img src="@MyClass.GetImgSrc()" /> Tiles
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET have already a utility to create html from string with System.Web.MVC

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(linkInnerHtml)
```

In you case

```
@Html.ActionLink(MvcHtmlString.Create(linkInnerHtml), "action" ... )
```